# Can a magnificent mansion be created on a demiplane?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Is there any problem with casting spells that create extraplanar spaces (like the *mage's magnificent mansion*) while on a demiplane?

My wizard wants to create a permanent demiplane (using *create demiplane* and *permanency*), but I'm not sure whether just to make the demiplane larger or to have him cast *mansion* each day he spends there for more space and the goodies that with the *mansion*.

I found nothing *preventing* the creation of extradimensional spaces in demiplane, but I want to be sure I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## There's no problem

The spells *[create demiplane](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-demiplane) et al.* have no restrictions about making on the created demiplanes openings to other demiplanes, whether such openings are created by a spell like [*rope trick*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/rope-trick) or [*mage's magnificent mansion*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mage-s-magnificent-mansion) or by a magic item like a [*bag of holding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding).

Casting *mansion* while on the created demiplane makes the *mansion* entrance  really hard to find by anyone trying to hunt you down but also obviously costs a 7th-level spell. I think most folks likely consider the demiplane itself already secure *enough*, but if you need a place to hide an army or make a refugee camp, and the created demiplane's not big enough on its own, also slapping a *mansion* entrance on the demiplane is a good plan.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Mage in question is a hedonistic guy and likes the luxury of having servants tending to him and the availability of a nine-course banquet. Those are things Create Demiplane can't offer.